# Can't read data in node.js from a Ajax POST request

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, post

I need help with a very simple problem, but which for some reason I can't solve. I have a ajax post request that send data to a node.js server. From the server side, data seems to be received, but I am not able to retrieve the data fields.

Extract from the Client side:

```
function validateUser() 
{   
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/authAjax",
      data: {
        username: "myusr",
        password: "mypsw"
      },
      success: function( result ) {alert("OK");},
      error: function( result ) {alert("ERR");}
    });
}
```

Extract from the Server side (node.js):

```
app.post('/authAjax', function(req, res)
{
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(req.body);      // not working
        console.log(req.username);  // not working
        console.log(req.data);      // not working
        res.send("200");            
    });
});
```

The `res.send("200");` is executed, but I have no chance to get the passed `username` and `password` values. Could someone give any hint here?

Answer (score 0):

These were missing on node.js side:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());  
app.use(express.json());
```

And the data are accessible with:

```
req.body
```